# Trying to call on switch case in a class from program.cs

Tags: c#

Iam creating a calculator and using switch case for the operators ( +,-,*,/ etc.) But the problem is that I dont know what exactly to type in the class. I have tried abstract and
I got 0 errors, but I couldn't call it on program.cs (nothing happend).

tal1 and tal2 is the numbers in double form that are going to be operated ( tal1 + tal2) example.

Metod is a string that is typed by a user and choosing a operator between (+,-,* etc).

metod is used in switch case to be determined what to write line.

```
using MyCalculat;

namespace SwitchOP
{
    public class SwCase : ReadInfo
    {
        public static void Cases()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HEJ");
        }


        private double tal1 { get; set; }
        private double tal2 { get; set; }
        private string metod
        {
            get
            {
                return metod;
            }

            set
            {

                switch (metod) // Här används switch case metoden. Vi använder stringen metod som vi deklarerade i början.
                {

                    case "+": // Ifall användaren har skrivit in +. Då kommer vi hit och gör följande.
                        Console.WriteLine("Resultat " + (tal1 + tal2)); // Skriver ut resultat samt adderar tal1 och tal2.
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break; // Bryter switch casen och går ut ur den.

                    case "-": // Samma gäller här fast med minus
                        Console.WriteLine("Resultat " + (tal1 - tal2));
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case "*":
                        double res = tal1 * tal2; // Skapar en double med namn res och lägger in värdet tal1 gånger tal2.
                        Math.Round(res, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // Här avrundrar vi värdet vi multiplicerade och använder endast två decimaler i vårat resultat.
                        Console.WriteLine("Resultat " + (res)); // Skriver ut resultat med double res.
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case "/":

                        if (tal2 == 0) // om tal2 är lika med 0 går vi in i en if-sats, efter att man försökt dela med 0.
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Det går ej att dela med 0");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Ditt andra tal var " + tal2);
                            Console.WriteLine("Skriv om ditt andra tal"); // Användaren får en ny chans att skriva ett andra tal.
                            tal2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Tal2 får ett nytt värde
                            Console.WriteLine("Resultat: " + (tal1 / tal2));
                        }

                        else // Om andra talet in är lika med 0 så kommer vi hit direkt.
                            Console.WriteLine("Resultat " + (tal1 / tal2));
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case "C": // Räkna ut Celsius  till F
                        Console.WriteLine("Resultat " + (tal1 * 9 / 5 + 32));
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case "F":
                        tal1 = tal1 - 32;
                        tal1 = tal1 * 5; // räknar ut F till celsius
                        tal1 = tal1 / 9;
                        Console.WriteLine("Resultat " + (tal1));
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Hej!"); // Switch casen kommer hit och ska skriva hej om något fel uppstår ( Egentligen används inte default just nu för att if-satsen längre upp uteslår allt annat än +,-,*,/  )
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Environment.Exit(0); // Programmet avslutas.
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently both your getter and your setter will just call the getter recursively. Fundamentally I suspect you should have a *method* to do the actual calculation, rather than putting it all in a property setter.

Comment: Try moving your code from set to Main(). get and set are not probably what you are looking for.

Comment: perhaps you need to keep property method as -> public string metod {get; set;} (and the talx too as public) then define a public double GetValue { 
                get {
                    [put your code here and RETURN the result]
                    }
            }